# JAVA: Hangman game i need it to only reveal the first occurrence of the guess

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I am taking an intro class to Java and we have a project that deals with a hangman game. I have most of the code worked out but i can't get this part to work the way i want. First, the program prompts the user for a letter, I need it to reveal just the first time the letter is in the word. lets say the word is apple and I enter p, I just want to to go _ p _ _ _ instead of _ pp _ _. I think i need to use indexof or something similar but I could use some help figuring which to use and how to apply it.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { //check if the letter is correct
            if (word.charAt(i) == letter && wordToShow.charAt(i) == '_') 
            {   //checking only free spaces _
                System.out.println("Good!");
                wordToShow.setCharAt(i, letter);  //change '_' to the letter guessed
                guessed += letter;                  //save the letter
                guessed += '+';                     //mark the success
                if (wordToShow.indexOf("_") == -1) 
                {   //if there more unsolved letters?
                    return true;        //there is no '_' symbols, all letters on their places
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is stop checking once you've found one.  Simply insert a break statement in the if block after everything else and it will exit the for loop and stop checking subsequent letters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { //check if the letter is correct
        if (word.charAt(i) == letter && wordToShow.charAt(i) == '_') 
        {   //checking only free spaces _
            System.out.println("Good!");
            wordToShow.setCharAt(i, letter);  //change '_' to the letter guessed
            guessed += letter;                  //save the letter
            guessed += '+';                     //mark the success
            if (wordToShow.indexOf("_") == -1) 
            {   //if there more unsolved letters?
                return true;        //there is no '_' symbols, all letters on their places
            }      
            break;
        }
}
```